# Extract words from String and assign it to UNIX Variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have one automation thought. Here are full details.
Each user sends me one SQL query and then I need to execute below steps using automation script.

1. Run a SQL query file.sql which exists in the UNIX server using Unix shell script.

   ```
   select count(*) as cnt from emp where employee='Scott' and job='Manager' and Salary>10000 and location='Chicago' and deptno=10 and hike_in_perc=15 and deptname is not null;
   ```

   Take the query output into the UNIX variable.
2. If count > 0 then exit.
3. If count =0 then, I need to update the Input table emp data based on the where clause values given by the user automatically. (So that if I re-run the above query I will get count >0).

   My target is that when I run a SQL query given by the user, should get records count >0. To achieve this updating the input table with hardcoded values mentioned in the WHERE clause.

   ```
   update emp set employee='Scott',job='Manager',Salary=10001(need to manipulate*),location='Chicago',deptno=10,hike_in_perc=15,deptname='ABC'(need to manipulate if value is not NULL*);
   ```
4. Re-run the SQL Query again to make sure count >0.

Below query related to step 3 which I have started to work on the automation.

I have a text file (`cols.txt`) which contains the data (Tab Delimiter) like below.

```
employee='Scott' job='Manager' Salary=10000 location='Chicago' deptno=10
hike_in_perc=15 deptname='Accounts'
```

File contains `col_name=Value` format and number of columns are not limited and have multiple files with different number of columns and their values.

Could you please help me how can I extract each column value along with column name like:

```
var1=employee='Scott'
var2=job='Manager'
.....etc
```

My final goal is to use these values in the UPDATE statement in the SQL query. Please suggest me a good way to accomplish this. Thank you In advance.

I have tried to use CUT and SED but not helpful and am not getting expecting result.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried and to clearly explain what was wrong with your attempts. Note: if you don't have tabs in your column names or in values you can try `sed 's/\t/\n/g' cols.txt`.

Comment: What characters are permitted between the single quoted strings? Only upper and lower case ASCII?

Comment: Don't populate a bunch of scalar variables with suffixes 1-N, populate an array, e.g. `arr[1]="employee='Scott'"`, An associative array might make the most sense for your needs though, `arr['employee']='Scott'`. There's lots of answers on this forum and stackexchange showing how do do either of those.

Comment: you can use `$employee $job $Salary ...` if you source the file `source ./col.txt`

Comment: You want count `>0`, or count `=1`? Because those are very different criteria.

Comment: I want count>0. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your *intent*, it might be simpler than you're thinking.

You could potentially just use the data almost "as-is" by swapping the tabs for commas, ***assuming you are going to add a WHERE clause***. Obviously, ***never*** update a table without a `WHERE`; I've added a simplistic placeholder.

```
$: cat file
employee='Scott'        job='Manager'   Salary=10000    location='Chicago'      deptno=10       hike_in_perc=15 deptname='Accounts'
employee='bob'  job='peon'      Salary=100      location='hell' deptno=666      hike_in_perc=1  deptname='drudgery'

$: while IFS=$'\t' read -r line; do echo "UPDATE sometable SET $line WHERE somecondition='$somevalue';";done < <( tr $'\t' , < file )
UPDATE sometable SET employee='Scott',job='Manager',Salary=10000,location='Chicago',deptno=10,hike_in_perc=15,deptname='Accounts' WHERE somecondition='foo';
UPDATE sometable SET employee='bob',job='peon',Salary=100,location='hell',deptno=666,hike_in_perc=1,deptname='drudgery' WHERE somecondition='foo';

$: while IFS=$'\t' read -r line; do echo "UPDATE sometable SET ${line//$'\t'/,} WHERE somecondition='$somevalue';";done<file
UPDATE sometable SET employee='Scott',job='Manager',Salary=10000,location='Chicago',deptno=10,hike_in_perc=15,deptname='Accounts' WHERE somecondition='bar';
UPDATE sometable SET employee='bob',job='peon',Salary=100,location='hell',deptno=666,hike_in_perc=1,deptname='drudgery' WHERE somecondition='bar';
```

If, for example, your first two fields *were* your condition...

```
$: while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b new; do echo "UPDATE sometable SET ${new//$'\t'/,} WHERE $a AND $b;";done<file
UPDATE sometable SET Salary=10000,location='Chicago',deptno=10,hike_in_perc=15,deptname='Accounts' WHERE employee='Scott' AND job='Manager';
UPDATE sometable SET Salary=100,location='hell',deptno=666,hike_in_perc=1,deptname='drudgery' WHERE employee='bob' AND job='peon';
```

For large datasets, this will be faster with `awk`.

```
$: awk -F$'\t' '{printf "UPDATE sometable SET "; for(i=3;i<NF;i++)printf "%s,",$i; print $NF " WHERE " $1 " AND " $2 ";"}' file
UPDATE sometable SET Salary=10000,location='Chicago',deptno=10,hike_in_perc=15,deptname='Accounts' WHERE employee='Scott' AND job='Manager';
UPDATE sometable SET Salary=100,location='hell',deptno=666,hike_in_perc=1,deptname='drudgery' WHERE employee='bob' AND job='peon';
```

These make a ***lot*** of assumptions, such as that each line of your files is all the data needed to update one record - but I thought it was a worth mentioning in case this was more of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

If your files could be multiple lines, but each file is one possible UPDATE, then maybe another approach -

```
$: cat f2
employee='Scott'    job='Manager'
Salary=10000    location='New York' deptno=10
hike_in_perc=15 deptname='Accounts'

$: conditions="$(<f2)"
$: echo "select count(*) as cnt from emp where ${conditions//[$'\n\t']/ AND };"
select count(*) as cnt from emp where employee='Scott' AND job='Manager' AND Salary=10000 AND location='New York' AND deptno=10 AND hike_in_perc=15 AND deptname='Accounts';
```

Good luck.

Comment: You're very welcome. Just make sure you test and verify, especially that `WHERE` clause.

Comment: In particular, try changing `Chicago` to `New York` to ensure the solution works when the data contains spaces as that's a common point of failure for such scripts.

Comment: I have updated my actual requirement in my question. Could you please read it once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{c=0}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "var"++c"="$i}' cols.txt
var1=employee='Scott'
var2=job='Manager'
var3=Salary=10000
var4=location='Chicago'
var5=deptno=10
var6=hike_in_perc=15
var7=deptname='Accounts'
```

Comment: Above script is working fine, however it is only printing the expected values. Could you please suggest how to create UNIX variables like var1, var2, var3... varn instead of printing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will parse the file declare the variables.

```
for var in $(cat cols.txt);do declare "$var"; done

[~] echo $employee
'Scott'
[~] echo $job
'Manager'
[~] echo $Salary
10000
[~] echo $location
'Chicago'
[~] echo $deptno
10
[~] echo $hike_in_perc
15
[~] echo $deptname
'Accounts'
```

Comment: [Don't read files with a `for` loop.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) Use [while](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Otherwise, I kinda like this approach, so long as all the column names are valid `bash` variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't populate a bunch of scalar variables with suffixes 1-N, populate an array, e.g. `arr[1]="employee='Scott'"`, An associative array might make the most sense for your needs though, `arr['employee']='Scott'`. There's lots of answers on this forum and stackexchange showing how do do either of those but yours is slightly complicated by having multiple tab-separated assignments per line so here you go:

```
declare -A arr
while IFS='=' read -r tag val; do
    arr["$tag"]="$val"
done < <(tr $'\t' $'\n' < file)
```

with the result being that `arr[]` is populated with the tag (name) to value mappings:

```
declare -p arr
declare -A arr=([employee]="'Scott'" [job]="'Manager'" [deptno]="10" [location]="'Chicago'" [deptname]="'Accounts'" [hike_in_perc]="15" [Salary]="10000" )
```

The above assumes there are no duplicate tags in the input since there are none in the example the OP provided.

Comment: Does this need a secondary inner parse to keep records from overwriting? `while read -r -a line; do declare -A arr=(); for item in "${line[@]}"; do arr["${item%%=*}"]="${item#=*}"; done; declare -p arr; done<file`

Comment: @PaulHodges are you asking about how to handle duplicate tags in the input? I just updated my answer to state it assumes that doesn't happen.

Comment: But the example only gives one line. I assumed the actual input file would have multiple lines - OP doesn't actually say. If all the files are single-line, then it's a moot point.

Comment: @PaulHodges the example input is 2 lines so I just take it as a file of tag-value pairs that aren't always each on a separate line.

Comment: Good call. I actually read that line break as accidental. Those details matter. :)

Comment: number of lines are not constant, it depends on the query provided by the user. It may be one line or multiple lines. Thank you for your support and time.